# How to show $\binom{2p}{p} \equiv 2\pmod p$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients, catalan-numbers

how to prove $\forall p$ prime :

$\binom{2p}{p} \equiv 2 \pmod p$ we have:

$\binom{2p}{p} = \frac{2p (2p-1)(2p-3)...1}{p!p!}$ but how to continue?

Comment: Your formula for $\binom{2p}{p}$ is wrong. If you want to write out the factors of the numerator, there shouldn't still be a factorial $!$ in it.

Comment: When $p\geq 5$ is prime, there's an even stronger theorem: $\binom{pa}{pb}\equiv \binom{a}{b}\pmod {p^3}$. That's probably more than you need to show, however. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's very particular case of [Lucas' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27_theorem). Compute in $\mathbf{Z}_{p}[x]$
$$
(1 + x)^{2p} = \sum_{i=0}^{2p} \binom{2p}{i} x^{i},
$$
but also
$$
(1 + x)^{2p} = ((1 + x)^{p})^{2} = (1 + x^{p})^{2} = 1 + 2 x^{p} + x^{2p}
$$
and now compare the coefficients of $x^{p}$ in the two expressions.

Comment: Thanks @HagenvonEitzen. I have used so many times Lucas' theorem *for business*...

Comment: Brilliant!!! +1

Answer (score 5):

Back to basics:
$$
\begin{align}
&{2p\choose p} \equiv 2 \mod p\\
\Leftrightarrow&\frac{(p+1)(p+2)...(p+p-1)(2p)}{p!} \equiv 2 \mod p\\
\Leftrightarrow&\frac{(p+1)(p+2)...(p+p-1)2}{(p-1)!} \equiv 2 \mod p\\
\Leftrightarrow&p\ \text{ divides }\ \left[\frac{(p+1)(p+2)...(p+p-1)2}{(p-1)!}-2\right]\tag{1} \\
\Leftrightarrow&p\ \text{ divides }\ (p-1)!\left[\frac{(p+1)(p+2)...(p+p-1)2}{(p-1)!}-2\right]\tag{2} \\
\Leftrightarrow&(p+1)(p+2)...(p+p-1)2 \equiv 2(p-1)! \mod p\\
\Leftrightarrow&(1)(2)...(p-1)2 \equiv 2(p-1)! \mod p\\
\Leftrightarrow&2(p-1)! \equiv 2(p-1)! \mod p,
\end{align}
$$
where $(1)\Leftarrow(2)$ because $(p-1)!$ does not contain the prime factor $p$.